# Prevent TouchableWithoutFeedback keyboard dismiss on Pressable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a component with a dismiss keyboard touchable. However, I also have a button that creates a new component that needs text input, but the keyboard is getting dismissed and I have to tap again to pull up the keyboard. Is there a way to prevent the keyboard dismissal for that button only?

Simplified code example:

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
  <TextInput/>
  <Pressable/> // currently pressing this dismisses the keyboard. is there a way to prevent that?
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```